# zeroing a disk with dd vs Disk Utility

Tags: mac-osx, dd, zero-fill

I'm attempting to zero a disk on my Mac OS X machine.  I'm going for complete zeros and unformatted, so I think of `dd`.  Unfortunately the maximum throughput I've managed to get out of `dd` is 7MB/s.  Just for grins I tried disk utility and it has a throughput of 19MB/s.  What gives?  I've tried changing the bs option on `dd` to all sorts of values, but it still hovers around 7MB/s.  Why is disk utility so much faster?

Answer (score 5):

That sounds pretty slow for dd, what was the infile you were using? I prefer dd to Disk Utility.app just because it's faster and I find it's easier to work with. The command you should use is:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/[blockdevice] bs=1M`

Comment: I used that exact command, but the throughput stayed at about 7MB/s while Disk Utility was roughly 3 times that.  What gives??

Comment: @jdizzle when using dd or similar software (eg. dd_rescue) that uses /dev/diskX naming scheme, on macOS is important to use /dev/rdiskX format (r means raw unbuffered access straight to the device). more details - https://superuser.com/a/892768/328636

Comment: Where can I learn `blockdevice` id?

Answer (score 1):

Disk utility may be faster because it writes to a raw disk. When using DD, try writing dd as a raw disk by putting an `r` infront if `disk` in `/dev/disk`. Therefore your dd command should look like the following:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/rdiskX bs=16m
```

You may want to change the lowercase m after 16 to an uppercase M depending on if you are using dd with mac os or linux.